# Swift NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, swift3

I keep getting a NSInternalInconsistencyException error but I am registering a custom cell. I am trying to add a `UICollectionViewController` to a `UIPageViewController`. What am I missing? It appears the `UIPageViewController` is creating a new instance of my class, when ever I print out the objects being passed into `cellForItemAt` `IndexPath` the memory addresses are two different memory addresses if it were the same class, I assume it would be the same memory address.

```
<UICollectionView: 0x7fa89019a600; frame = (0 0; 300 300); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x604000a54dc0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x604000e23e60>; contentOffset: {0, -20}; contentSize: {300, 70}; adjustedContentInset: {20, 0, 0, 0}> collection view layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fa88ef8bb30>
DILLY 2
<UICollectionView: 0x7fa890153600; frame = (0 0; 300 300); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x604000a53e60>; layer = <CALayer: 0x604000e21e80>; contentOffset: {0, -20}; contentSize: {300, 70}; adjustedContentInset: {20, 0, 0, 0}> collection view layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fa88ef8b6f0>
2017-12-07 00:24:17.043446-0600 Peeke[52042:9993894]
```

In the parent of the UIPageViewController im just adding the controller.

```
viewWillAppear:
    self.addChildViewController(self.venueProjector)
    self.view.addSubview(self.venueProjector.view)
```

any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
    class VenueProjector: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    var venue: Venue!

    override init(transitionStyle style: UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle, navigationOrientation: UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation, options: [String : Any]? = nil) {
        super.init(transitionStyle: style, navigationOrientation: navigationOrientation, options: options)
    }//end init

    convenience init(Venue: Venue){
        self.init(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
        self.venue = Venue
    }//end init

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }//end init

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.dataSource = self
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300)
        let viewControllers = [MarkFeedCollectionView(Venue: venue)]
        self.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }//end func

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        let col = MarkFeedCollectionView(Venue: venue)
        return col
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let col  = MarkFeedCollectionView(Venue: venue)
        return col
    }
}//end class


class MarkFeedCollectionView: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

        let cellID: String = "FeedCell"
        var marks = [Mark]()
        var venueID: String!

        var markFeed: UICollectionView = {
            let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = {
                let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
                flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
                flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
                flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 1, height:1)
                return flowLayout
            }()
            var colview = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1), collectionViewLayout: layout)
            colview.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            colview.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
            colview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = false
            return colview
        }()


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        override init(collectionViewLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout) {
            super.init(collectionViewLayout: layout)
        }

        convenience init(Venue: Venue){
            let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = {
                let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
                flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
                flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
                flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 1, height:1)
                return flowLayout
            }()
            self.init(collectionViewLayout: layout)
            self.marks.append( Mark(name: Venue.venueName, ID: Venue.VENUE_ID, message: Venue.getVenueDeal()))
            self.venueID = Venue.VENUE_ID
            self.view.addSubview(self.markFeed)
            self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300)
            self.markFeed.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300)
            self.markFeed.delegate = self

            self.markFeed.dataSource = self
        }//end convenience init

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            self.markFeed.register(FeedCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellID)
            getUpdatedMarks()
        }//end func

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }//end init

        func populateCollectionView(mark: Mark){
            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: marks.count, section: 0)
            self.marks.append(mark)
            self.markFeed.insertItems(at: [indexPath])
            let item = markFeed.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) - 1
            let lastItemIndex = NSIndexPath(item: item, section: 0)

            markFeed.scrollToItem(at: lastItemIndex as IndexPath, at: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.bottom, animated: true)
        }//end func


        internal override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

            return self.marks.count

        }//end func

        internal override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

            print(collectionView)
            let liveFeedCell: FeedCell  = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: self.cellID, for: indexPath) as! FeedCell

            liveFeedCell.populateMark(mark: marks[indexPath[1]], venueID: self.venueID)
            liveFeedCell.likeButton?.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "likeButton_notToggled"), for: .normal)
            markFeed.layoutIfNeeded()
            return liveFeedCell
        }//end func

        internal func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
            let message = marks[indexPath[1]].message
            if message.count >= 141{
                let multiplier = message.count/141
                let height = CGSize(width: 0, height: multiplier * 70).height
                return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: height)
            }else{
                return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 70)
            }
        }//end func

        private func getUpdatedMarks(){
            let Webservice = WebService()
            let paramaters: Parameters = ["venueID": self.venueID]
            Webservice.getRequestToServer(route: "mark", parameters: paramaters){responseObj, error in

                let arr = JSON(responseObj as Any)
                let markArr = arr["marks"]
                if markArr.isEmpty{
                    return
                }
                for mark in markArr{
                    let (_ , m) = mark
                    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.marks.count, section: 0)
                    self.marks.append(Mark(mark: m))
                    self.markFeed.insertItems(at: [indexPath])
                };
            };
        }//end func
    }//end class
```

Comment: You are creating a second `UICollectionView` in your `UICollectionViewController`. `UICollectionViewController` already has a `UICollectionView`. You should be setting up that collection view instead of creating another one.

Comment: Ah thanks, I wasn't aware. That explains why I was getting a different memory address.